# Check if an IO stream is blocked in C#

Tags: c#, stream, interactive

In `C#`, one can run a process and interact with it using its `stdin` and `stdout`.

Interactive programs however sometimes block waiting for input. The stream is not closed, and when calling the `ReadLine` method, the method blocks until more data becomes available.

Is there a way to verify if there is currently still data available on the stdin without blocking (if no more data is available, the program must feed the stdin of the process)...

Code example:

```
this.process = new Process ();
this.process.StartInfo.FileName = "foo";
this.process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--nowarnings -i";
this.process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
this.process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
this.process.Start ();
this.stdin = this.process.StandardInput;
this.stdout = this.process.StandardOutput;
this.stdin.WriteLine ("command1");
while (!stdout.EndOfStream) {
    Console.WriteLine (stdout.ReadLine ());
}
this.stdin.WriteLine ("command2");
```

Comment: You can try just pushing data into stdin until the process isn't dead in a separate thread (if it should end after all required data has been supplied).

Comment: No it's an interactive program. Based on the output of the program, one needs to feed new input... Therefore one cannot push all the input until the process dies...

Comment: So you'll need to parse the output on the fly to determine whether it's the end of this particular bit. You haven't provided much information. In general you can never be sure if there is just a long delay in the external problem (e.g. some heavy computation), or is it waiting for input.

Comment: That's true... But since the program runs on the local machine and the program is quite fast, a timeout of let's say 10 ms should be sufficient...

Comment: Well then, there you have your answer :)

Comment: The problem is that if one sets a timeout, the entire stream is killed... :( The program needs the stream for future actions.

Comment: Don't know what do you mean by a "killed stream". Perhaps you could present a code sample?

Comment: Well the stream is "closed" (the program throws an IOException and is unable to read future content of the stream...

Comment: If the stream gets closed then probably the child process has finished. Again, it is hard to guess what is happening without the actual code example. You can also consider reading from the child output asynchronously (see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question (in case somebody is looking for a similar answer) with a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Console.KeyAvailable` property to check if there is a symbol available in the input stream. However you should use `Console.ReadKey` method in conjunction with `KeyAvailable` because `ReadLine` will block until the `stdin` receives newline sequence or end-of-file.